# Is it possible to get further information about phases during AWS CodeBuild?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codebuild

I'm trying to get further information out of AWS CodeBuild's BUILD phases. I'd to see the individual steps, rather than one big BUILD phase, in case something fails during the build step.

I already looked into the CodeBuild operations, but I can't seem to find one that returns what I want.
Maybe I can do something inside of the buildspec.yml?

I hope someone can help me

Answer (score 1):

When creating the build project, click Cloudwatch logs...

[image]

... this will generate detailed logs on each command execution:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can check the progress with CloudWatch. Check [an example with CodeBuild logs config](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/create-project.html#create-project-cli).